# does it make sense to have Pure logical (No rendering) react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and trying to figure out a good design but couldn't reach a decision from Googling. Here is my problem:

I have some old JavaScript code that deals mostly with my app's WebSocket logics and a little bit of DOM manipulation using the WebSocket data. I wanted to refactor those code into React component because they seem much cleaner and maintainable. But from what I have gathered, React components are used for rendering HTML elements, which leaves me wondering whether it makes sense to have some pure logical React components that renders nothing or to keep all WS logic in my old JS and only refactor the parts that requires rendering.

Thanks!

Comment: I  think this is ultimately going to be a matter of taste, so someone will probably vote to close as opinion-based. However, I generally treat my communication layer as a non-component module which is then imported by the components that need to make requests. (If you use a data-management framework 'around' React, like Redux, then socket logic probably belongs there)

Comment: [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) uses purely logical components for implementing routing with React components. There's no definitive answer to this question, but react-router is a good example of how non-visual components can work.

Comment: @SMcCrohan I think I understand the approach. But for this design, how will the communication layer deliver the messages to the components? Or do all the components just listen to the message receive event?

Comment: FWIW: https://kyleshevlin.com/renderless-components seems to love this idea. Me too, but I'm a n00b to ReactJS.